# Interact with a MySQL database from Windows command line

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to use MySQL/MariaDB from the command line.  In Windows, when I type "mysqld" to start the database server, the command prompt to run the MySQL client and type SQL disappears.  How do I start the server *and* interact with the database on the command line?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the MySQL shell from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/shell/).

And then start it like this:

```
mysqlsh --uri user@localhost
```

Take a look at the official [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-getting-started.html)

Answer (score 2):

You're running **mysqld** (the MySQL daemon) successfully. It's a server and now serves MySQL.

After that, you need to run `mysql`, the MySQL client from the command-line interface for interacting with the server.

Comment: Do you understand your own writing? Are you using machine translation (e.g., [Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate))?